# Background image with Vue

Tags: vue.js, background

I want to add a background image in my App.vue file in my Vue project.

I tried this with a file titled 'leaves.jpg' in my assets folder but the result is blank.

```
<template>
<div :style="{'background-image':'url(./assets/leaves.jpg)'}">
</div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add height and width to div.

```
<div :style="{'background-image':'url(./assets/leaves.jpg)'}" 
      style="width=100px; height="100px"
/>
```

assuming your path to asset folder is correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to require it:

`` :style="{'background-image': `url(${require('@/assets/leaves.jpg')})`}" ``

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the background image in style tag as below.

```
<style>
div {
  background-image: url('custom1.png')
}
</style>
```